# Mapping data from Excel sheet1 to sheet2 creates duplicate column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map values from Sheet1 to sheet2 using an pandas dataframe, Having Column names listed in sheet2, but when i writes data into sheet 2, it leaves the first column null and append data into an duplicate column.

It also happens when i am trying to print dataframe2

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\notepad.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\notepad.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')


df2['col1'] = df1['col3']
df2['col2'] = df1['col5']
df2['col3'] = df1['col8']
df2['col4'] = df1['col6']
```

When trying to print df1 its gives correct data
But when trying to print df2 column gets duplicate with first column have null values

```
print(df2)

Output

col1 col2 col3 col4  col1 col2 col3 col4
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   Ind  Aus  Nz   Aus
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   Sri  Afg  Chi  Ber
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   Usa  Uk   Un   Ind
```

How to avoid duplicate columns having Null values

Answer (score 0):

To avoid potential issue of the columns having any non-standard characters in their names or anything else weird going on with the column names, have you tried:

```
df2[0] = df1['col3']
df2[1] = df1['col5']
df2[2] = df1['col8']
df2[3] = df1['col6']
```

Also, what's the output of print(df1) please?